# Interactive Document (takes input gives output) in Rpubs

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to publish an RMarkdown file to Rpubs that takes input and gives out put from the Rpubs site? I want to create a simple calculator related to my job that takes a few inputs and gives an output and, if possible, publish to Rpubs for people to view and use.

SHINY: I know this is what shiny is for, creating interactive apps, but I dont know it very well or how to implement an app I create for multiple people to use, or how to imbed the link to the app, and so on. Just trying to see if this is possible in things I already know how to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPubs is for HTML documents that don't require R calculations on the backend.  In some instances, there can be some degree of interactivity e.g., brushing and linking plots, filtering data and having the filter propagate to a plot. These happen through the [`crosstalk`](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/)   package.  However, it sounds like you need a shiny app that can take inputs and have R do some calculation of those on the back end. You could host your app on [shinyapps.io](https://shinyapps.io)

It's also possible, depending on how complicated the calculations are, that the entire app could be written in native javascript, which wouldn't require a server-side computation, so could be hosted on any website.